# Extract some links after using Selenium -- get.attribute

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, href

I use the following code (it works) to extract all attribute of `href` on a web page. 
Now I would like to just extract a few links from the total set of links extracted using a loop: the links on which I am interested in contains the following path `"http://www.nba.com/teams/hawks"` as an example.

The code used for extracting all `href` is as follows:

```
elems = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
for elem in elems:
    print (elem.get_attribute("href"))
```

Answer (score 0):

using list comprehensions:

```
url = 'http://www.nba.com/teams/hawks'
elems = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
hrefs = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in elems]
my_hrefs = [href for href in hrefs if url in href]
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution also gives an idea for tackling another issue! Thank you!